# Application just closes (no error or smth) when run from VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

Problem is that application closes without any error, VS stays opened.
I have multiple dynamically created `FileSystemWatchers`, all of them have eventhandler on "Created" event. So this eventhandler method looks like this :

```
void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
    filesDataGrid.Rows.Add(f1.Name);
    foreach (TLPclass table in parameterForm.getParameters)
    {
       //uses some funcion form another class
    }
}
```

Line which causes program to close is the one where I'm adding File name to `DataGridView - filesDataGrid.Rows.Add(f1.Name);` 
Also runs OK without that line.
Weird thing is that application runs normally, when launched from .exe file in projects folder. I can't see error in my code, but I guess theres something awfully wrong with it, if it doesn't even show error message.
And - what are the most common reasons why program could just shut down with no warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FileSystemWatcher` will trigger the events in a separate thread. The logic inside the event handlers will need to take that fact in consideration and perform any synchronization needed.  So you'll need something like this:

```
private void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (filesDataGrid.InvokeRequired)
    {
        filesDataGrid.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { watcher_FileCreated(sender, e); });
    }
    else
    {
        FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        filesDataGrid.Rows.Add(f1.Name);
        foreach (TLPclass table in parameterForm.getParameters)
        {
           //uses some funcion form another class
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that explains the cross thread error. But can I somehow update table within that eventhandler method?

Comment: @andree - See my example.  You need to Invoke back to the GUI thread to update it.

Comment: This worked. I should check the "Invoke" methods for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function with a Try{}catch (Exception ex) { } block.
i Would think it is because DataGridRow needs to be created with the variables from the FileSystemWatcher first.

e.g

```
DataGridViewRow row = filesDataGrid.NewRow();

row["columnname"] = f1.name;

filesDataGrid.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried try-catch, and i got "Cross thread operation no valid! filesDataGrid accesed from thread other than it was created on". Now i got something to work with. But still don't understand why it is cross thread, because it was created in the same class is being used from and no new thread are being created in code.

Comment: That normally means that you are trying to update the DataGrid on the same thred it is trying to watch for the change. So i would greate another Event Handler that is like UpdateDataGrid, and pass it the parameter, I am guessinf the fl.Name is on anothe thred. so cant directly update the Control directly. are you using Winforms? or WPF? etc..?

Comment: It's Winforms. I think I'll try eventhandler for adding info to DataGrid. Should work I think.