# C# Program Exits After Running Other Process

Tags: c#, process, 7zip

This problem is bizarre. I have never encountered anything like it before.
I am trying to make my program extract a file using 7zip. I have done this before in other programs and it was never too difficult. So I copy and pasted my code in:

```
Process process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        FileName = "7za.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        ErrorDialog = false,
        Arguments = "x -y -o\"" + outputPath +"\" \""+ inputFile +"\"",
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
    }
};
process.Start();
```

Immediately after this code has run my application terminates. It just disappears. It's certainly not meant to! I used the step into function and ran it. As soon as `process.Start();` had finished the program closed and returned me into Visual C#. It didn't run any `Application.Exit();` or anything, it just went away. There was no error awaiting me in Visual C#.
So I tried adding a `MessageBox.Show("Test");` to the end. Ran it in step mode. Did `process.Start();` fine, as soon as it executed the MessageBox code it disappeared again. I didn't even click ok in the message box (which showed up for about 0.2 seconds before the application terminated)

Comment: Are you getting an exception? `Process` can throw them, you know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if this code is in Main() then it will finish when your code is done executing. Can you post the full code where this snippet is contained?

You can wait for the process to finish by including

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

Checking the `ExitCode` might tell you if your process succeeded. And you can always redirect the StandardError to check the output of that too.

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I tried WaitForExit and it still disappeared, it is a Windows Forms Application so it shouldn't terminate. I tried try catch statements and no error was found. Anyway, I think I've asked the wrong question. I'll mark your answer as the best answer because its my fault it didn't work.

Comment: Could you explain what the problem was then? That way people who find this question won't be left in the dark for a solution.

Comment: I believe it was fairly specific to me. The location where I was extracting the file to a location where I had a FileSystemWatcher pointed at, which was causing this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195086/application-just-closes-no-error-or-smth-when-run-from-vs2010

Answer (score 1):

Try process.WaitForExit() after process.Start() ...

Comment: You still need to call Start() though.